# Property 'getLabelForValue' does not exist on type in Chart.js

Tags: typescript, charts

I have an error in `callback` method

```
TS2322:... Type `string | number` is not assignable to type `number`.                     Type `string` is not assignable to type `number`.
```

How to fix this problem?

```
import { ChartOptions } from "chart.js"

const options: ChartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  interaction: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false,
  },
  elements: {
    point: {
      radius: 1,
      pointStyle: 'circle',
      hoverRadius: 2,
      hoverBorderWidth: 3,
    },
    line: {
      fill: true,
    },
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      ticks: {
        // <--------- error is here --------->
        callback(val: number, index: number): string {
          return index % 2 === 0 ? this.getLabelForValue(val) : '';
        },
        color: 'red',
        maxRotation: 0,
        minRotation: 0,
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Your code contains incorrect syntax: `const = options: ChartOptions`. Please fix it and share reproducible example

Comment: `otherOptions` ?

Comment: The problem is that `val` argument in `callback` might be a string whereas `getLabelForValue` expects only number. First of all, get rid of explicit types in `callback` method and check whether `val` is number. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/mxBEZw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COnsider this example:

```js
import { ChartOptions } from "chart.js"

const options: ChartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  interaction: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false,
  },
  elements: {
    point: {
      radius: 1,
      pointStyle: 'circle',
      hoverRadius: 2,
      hoverBorderWidth: 3,
    },
    line: {
      fill: true,
    },
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      ticks: {
        callback(val, index): string {
          return index % 2 === 0 && typeof val === 'number' ? this.getLabelForValue(val) : '';
        },
        color: 'red',
        maxRotation: 0,
        minRotation: 0,
      }
    }
  }
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mxBEZw)

The problem is that `val` argument in callback might be a string whereas `getLabelForValue` expects only number. First of all, get rid of explicit types in callback method and check whether `val` is `number`

Answer (score 0):

```js
scales: {
        xAxes: [{

            gridLines: {
                display: false
            },
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,

                callback: function(value, index, values) {
                    return value.substr(0, 12);
                },

            },
        }],
```

worked for me